# How to inherit class values in CSS

Tags: css, inheritance, frontend

How can I inherit from a:link, a:visited, a:active to .menunav:hover

I have code like this

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
   color: white !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

.menunav:hover {
   color: white !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   background: #333;
   transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

I want to inherit

`color: white !important; 
text-decoration: none !important;`

Answer (score 0):

To have those properties in the second element type, you can either copy-paste the properties into the second rule, as you did above, or have the selector appear in both rules.

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active, .menunav:hover {
   color: white !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

.menunav:hover {
   background: #333;
   transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.menunav:hover,
a.menunav:link,
a.menunav:visited,
a.menunav:active {
   color: white !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
}
```